# Shorting if condition and switch case in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, switch-statement

I am writing a conjugation script.

If I want to change the word_stem of a verb, I need to find all combination of mood, tense and person for unregular verb.

**Example if condition**

```
if ($exceptionmodel->getValue () === ExceptionModel::MOUVOIR && (($mood->getValue () === Mood::Indicatif && $tense->getValue () === Tense::Present && in_array ( $person->getValue (), array (
        Person::FirstPersonSingular,
        Person::SecondPersonSingular,
        Person::ThirdPersonSingular,
        Person::ThirdPersonPlural 
) ) || $tense->getValue () === Tense::Passe) || ($mood->getValue () === Mood::Subjonctif && $tense->getValue () === Tense::Present && in_array ( $person->getValue (), array (
        Person::FirstPersonSingular,
        Person::SecondPersonSingular,
        Person::ThirdPersonSingular,
        Person::ThirdPersonPlural 
) ) || $tense->getValue () === Tense::Imparfait) || (($mood->getValue () === Mood::Imperatif && $tense->getValue () === Tense::Present && $person->getValue () === Person::FirstPersonSingular))))
```

How is it possible to short this condition? I have to add a lot of other if-condition like that.

I will also shorting the switch case for this example for the changed endings of the exception verb in another function:

**Example switch case**

```
case ExceptionModel::MOUVOIR :
    $ending [EndingWith::IR] [Mood::Indicatif] [Tense::Present] [Person::FirstPersonSingular] = 'eus';
    $ending [EndingWith::IR] [Mood::Indicatif] [Tense::Present] [Person::SecondPersonSingular] = 'eus';
    $ending [EndingWith::IR] [Mood::Indicatif] [Tense::Present] [Person::ThirdPersonSingular] = 'eut';
    $ending [EndingWith::IR] [Mood::Indicatif] [Tense::Present] [Person::ThirdPersonPlural] = 'euvent';

    $ending [EndingWith::IR] [Mood::Imperatif] [Tense::Present] [Person::FirstPersonSingular] = 'eus';

    $ending [EndingWith::IR] [Mood::Indicatif] [Tense::Passe] = array (
            Person::FirstPersonSingular => 'us',
            Person::SecondPersonSingular => 'us',
            Person::ThirdPersonSingular => 'ut',
            Person::FirstPersonPlural => 'ûmes',
            Person::SecondPersonPlural => 'ûtes',
            Person::ThirdPersonPlural => 'urent' 
    );
    $ending [EndingWith::IR] [Mood::Subjonctif] [Tense::Present] [Person::FirstPersonSingular] = 'euve';
    $ending [EndingWith::IR] [Mood::Subjonctif] [Tense::Present] [Person::SecondPersonSingular] = 'euves';
    $ending [EndingWith::IR] [Mood::Subjonctif] [Tense::Present] [Person::ThirdPersonSingular] = 'euve';
    $ending [EndingWith::IR] [Mood::Subjonctif] [Tense::Present] [Person::ThirdPersonPlural] = 'euvent';
    $ending [EndingWith::IR] [Mood::Subjonctif] [Tense::Imparfait] = array (
            Person::FirstPersonSingular => 'usse',
            Person::SecondPersonSingular => 'usses',
            Person::ThirdPersonSingular => 'ût',
            Person::FirstPersonPlural => 'ussions',
            Person::SecondPersonPlural => 'ussiez',
            Person::ThirdPersonPlural => 'ussent'
    );
```

How is it possible to short this switch case? I have to add a lot of other switch cases like that.

Comment: You could put your conditions into functions and call them, so the if statement is more readable. (BTW: Your code already looks way better :])

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks. Another SO member helped me to write the script from scratch. Could you please post an answer?  I have already a special function which is used as an expression for the if condition: `function word_stem_mouvoir_exception(InfinitiveVerb $infinitiveVerb) {
 return word_stem_length($infinitiveVerb, 6);
}`

Comment: If you plan to do much more work of this kind, you might want to learn about *Finite State Morphology* (google it).

Comment: I don't think this question fits on stack overflow, it fit's in the scope of [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) though I don't know how active that is these days. However I'd recommend you to _not_ create complex if statements like that. Ideally, aim for booleans, and use return-early to simplify code and keep it readable. [Example](https://gist.github.com/AD7six/d88e67bbe898412d7ea5). The odd whitespace is also not common/helpful.